# Как записать NSAttributedstring в rtf file?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

Подскажите, как я могу записать NSAttributedstring в rtf file? через macOS or iOS.
Я нашел очень старый ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178895/how-can-i-save-the-attributed-string-text-into-file-swift-cocoa
Но я не совсем понял что именно мне следует делать, и может существует более простой способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё что Вам нужно - получить `Data` для записи в файл. Для этого у `NSAttributedString` есть функция:

```
func rtf(from range: NSRange, documentAttributes dict: [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey : Any] = [:]) -> Data?
```

А потом просто её записать по нужному пути:

```
func saveToRtf(string: NSAttributedString, path: String) -> Bool {
    let rtfData = string.rtf(
        from: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length),
        documentAttributes: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf]
    )
    return FileManager.default.createFile(
        atPath: path,
        contents: rtfData,
        attributes: nil
    )
}
```

Результат для:

```
let string = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Test",
    attributes: [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.red,
        NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: NSColor.green
    ]
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: cool that's exactly what i wanted to hear, thank you!